# How to add data to rails app in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm about to add in a few users manually (because I want to make them admins eg `user.admin = true`. Previously, in development I've done this using seeds but I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that you aren't supposed to use seeds in this way in production. What else should I do?

Comment: What server are you using for your production environment? Apache? Heroku?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options, each with their own pros and cons.

- Set up the users in the Rails console

  - Advantage: simple, can customize as much as needed
  - Disadvantage: not reproducible
- Add users in a migration

  - Advantage: if this is a new table or relevant data exists in other tables, you can set up the new data right away as part of a migration
  - Disadvantage: not a standard use of migration scripts
- Set up users with a rake task

  - Advantage: code to reproduce your steps will be checked into your repo
  - Disadvantage: if you only want to do this once, a rake task is overkill

The best solution might be to add a script in the `scripts/` directory of your app detailing the steps, have this code reviewed by your team, and then run it with [`rails runner`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the production command line? If you're using Heroku you can do this:

```
$ heroku run rails console
> user = User.new
> user.name = "The name"
// repeat for all other fields
> user.admin = true
> user.save
```

Or if you already have them in the database as non-admins

```
$ heroku run rails console
> user = User.find_by(name: "Their Name")
> user.update_attribute(:admin, true)
```